# Get Phone number of selected name on done button click?

Tags: ios, arrays, search

Hi i am using search array to search the result of name that is working fine. But when i click to get the  phone number of selected names that does not get the correct number.
  i get response in dict like

```
  (
    { firstName = John;
       lastName = Appleseed;
       mobileNo = 8885555512;
    }
    {

           firstName = Abc;

            lastName = Xyz;

            mobileNo = 0123456789;

    }

    {

           firstName = Red;

            lastName = Xyz;

            mobileNo = 1234567890;

    }

    )
```

Code :-

```
groupMemberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        filterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        namesOFMember = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        namesOFMember = [objcontact.fullContactArrayWithUserDetail valueForKey:kFirstName];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if([filterArray count])
    {
        cell.labelName.text= filterArray[indexPath.row];

    }
    else if (groupMemberArray.count)
    {
        cell.labelName.text= groupMemberArray[indexPath.row];

    }
    else
    {

    }



    return cell;
}
- (IBAction)doneBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    selectedNumbers = [self getSelections];
    NSLog(@"My Selected No's %@",selectedNumbers);

}

-(NSArray *)getSelections
{

    NSMutableArray *multipleContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    multipleContacts = [objcontact.fullContactArrayWithUserDetail  valueForKey:kMobileNumber];


    NSMutableArray *selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in selectedIndexArray) {
        [selections addObject:[multipleContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return selections;
}
```

Did select code:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"Row selectioner : %d ",selectedRow);

    [selectedIndexArray addObject:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"the number of selected rows is %lu",(unsigned long)selectedIndexArray.count);

    if(filterArray.count)
    {
        NSArray *tempArry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[filterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], nil];
        filterArray = tempArry.mutableCopy;

        [groupMemberArray addObjectsFromArray:filterArray];


        NSLog(@"New Array in list %@",groupMemberArray);
        if(filterArray.count)
            [filterArray removeAllObjects];
    }

     _searchTF.text= @"";
    [_tableViewName reloadData];


}
```

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  

    NSString *strName = [[arrayTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
  
}

Comment: use this code for get the row data of tableview cell if any error then tell me

Comment: @Birendra i want to get the mobile number to their corresponding name, this is not working

Comment: any error occurs ?

Comment: @Birendra My requirement is to search name in searchTF and get their corresponding number on done button.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  

    NSString *strName = [[filterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"mobileNo"];
    
  
}

Comment: put only this code and remove (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @Birendra where to put your code ?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath below this method

Comment: But filterarray only have names check my search perdicate .. it doesnot contain mobile number

Comment: so you have to pass mobile no in filter array

Comment: how to do???/.. cos search is based on name

Comment: give me you search code

Comment: chk my qustion  i updated the code